# Как реализовать выбор только одного блока а не всех сразу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сейчас при клике на картинку с синим бордером, бордеры окрашиваются в красный у всех блоков. Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на конкретный блок, обводка окрашивалась только у него и текст возвращался обратно на not selected?

```js
$('.div').click(function() {

  if ( !($('.div').hasClass('selected')) ) {
      $('.div').addClass('selected');
      $('.p').text('selected text');
  } else {
    $('.div').removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div><p class="p">not selected</p>
```

Comment: могут ли быть выбраны одновременно несколько блоков?

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать следующее:

```js
$('.div').click(function() {
  var selectedBlock = $(this); // отбираем нажатый элемент
  $('.div').each(function() { // пробегаемся по всем блокам
    if (!$(this).is(selectedBlock)) { // Поиск всех НЕ выбранных элементов
      $(this).removeClass('selected'); // Убираем класс selected, так как он не выбран
      $(this).next().text('Not selected'); // Также отбираем следующий тэг после элемента, в нашем случае это тэг <p> сбрасываем на 'Not selected'
    }
  });
  
  if (selectedBlock.hasClass('selected')) { // А теперь проверяем нажатый элемент
    selectedBlock.removeClass('selected');
    selectedBlock.next().text('Not selected');
  } else {
    selectedBlock.addClass('selected');
    selectedBlock.next().text('Selected element');
  }

});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p">Not selected</p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p">Not selected</p>
<div class="div" style="background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg)"></div>
<p class="p">Not selected</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вариант с использованием замыканий(если элементов много, и проходить по ним циклом `forEach()` не целесообразно ):

```
var clicked = ''; // ссылка на кликнутый элемент
$('.div').click(e => {
  if (clicked == e.target) { // если кликнут один элемент два раза
    let str = $(e.target).next().text()
    return $(clicked).toggleClass('selected').next().text(str == 'Selected' ? 'Not selected' : 'Selected')
  }
  $(clicked).removeClass('selected').next().text('Not selected')
  $(e.target).addClass('selected').next().text('Selected')
  clicked = e.target; // сохраняем ссылку на элемент в замыкании
})
```